# Regular Expression PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use some regular expressions in PL/SQL.

I try to check the following pattern: LOKATIONS_ID => /LAND/ORT/GEBÄUDE/

I've tried this one:

```
create or replace function check_lok_id(lok_id in varchar2) return boolean
is
begin
  if regexp_like (lok_id, '^(/[A-Z]+?){3}/$)')
    then
      return true;
  else
    return false;
  end if;
end;
```

But unfortunately this one and several other regular expressions i've tested so far doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Your example won't match because the umlauted character `Ä` is not in the range `A-Z`.

Try this regex:

```
^(/\w+?){3}/$
```

Or if you want to match only uppercase letters, but from all languages:

```
^(/[[:upper:]]+?){3}/$
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87307e/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll test it at tuesday and give you some feedback.